# I have a dictionary of Pandas dataframes, how would I write them to separate sheets in an Excel file using openpyxl

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I want to iterate over a Python dictionary where the values are dataframes, and write each dataframe to a new sheet in a single XLS file, where the tab names are the keys of the Python dictionary.

How would I do this using openpyxl?

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you need to do that with `openpyxl`? If not, check the *duplicate*.